# mysql deleting oldest record in a table

Tags: mysql

Hi all I am trying to come up with a sql that will delete the single oldest row in a database, currently I have this:

```
DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE date_added IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
```

Will that only ever delete from the top of my database or will it pick at random?

Comment: It's not 'random', but without an ORDER BY clause (or a GROUP BY, or full knowledge of indexes) you cannot guarantee the results of a LIMIT.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `order by` and  try like this-

```
DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE date_added IS NOT NULL order by date_added asc LIMIT 1
```

For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Edited answer to update order by asc

Comment: Shouldn't `desc` be `asc`?

Comment: Jep, should be asc, dont know why everybody uses desc. with desc you delete the newest entry...Cant even upvote a single answer because of this :/

Comment: Someone from the community with some rank should edit the answer and select it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to order it by date, descending, so the first result is the oldest one, and then delete that first result.

```
DELETE FROM `videos` 
WHERE data_added IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY date_added DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

This solution will work as long as your `date_added` column is a MySQL Date type or a numeric type (e.g. Unix timestamp). If not, you shall cast the data or modify the structure of your database (I recommend the later).

In order to cast the data, you could do:

```
DELETE FROM `videos` 
WHERE data_added IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY Cast(date_added as date) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `videos` order by date_added desc LIMIT 1
```

If you just need to delete the oldest record use above query, otherwise need to check some condition use this one

```
DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE date_added IS NOT NULL order by date_added desc LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, you can match with minimum date value and then can delete the record.

```
DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE date_added = (SELECT min(date_added) from videos) AND date_added IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
```

And in second way, you can delete using order by clause.

```
 DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE date_added IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date_added ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DELETE FROM `videos` order by date_added DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also delete record by id(if it is auto incremented)

```
 DELETE FROM `videos` order by id DESC LIMIT 1
```

this will delete last record